# How to clear/reset/renew Session Cookie in ASP.net core (Razor pages) app on login or logout

Tags: asp.net-core, session-cookies, razor-pages, session-fixation

I am trying to get a new value for the Session Cookie for every new login. Basically, the value in the screenshot below should have a new random string every time a user logs in. This is to avoid Session Fixation.

I have tried the following :

On login :

```
Response.Cookies.Delete(".AspNetCore.Session");

HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Session"] = "123132" //does not allow to be set
```

On log out :

```
HttpContext.Session.Clear();

Response.Clear();

Session.Abandon() // Abandon is no longer available
```

But the value of the Session Cookie just does not change. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

[Session Cookie on Browser Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Gsp.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `Response.Cookies.Delete(".AspNetCore.Session");` in Logout to delete the cookie

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it,

On login :

```
Response.Cookies.Append("Test_cookie", "yo");
```

On log out :

```
 Response.Cookies.Delete("Test_cookie");
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Somehow, my AspNetCore.Session cookie does not get deleted along with the TestCookie. Is there some setting that could be stopping it from being cleared? Also, can i check, when the AspNetCore.Session reappears on login, is the value same as what was before logoff or is it a new value?

Comment: @Rocky Did you use "Response.Cookies.Delete(".AspNetCore.Session");" in Logout to delete the cookie?

Comment: How do you set  the value of the AspNetCore.Session ?

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I added Response.Cookies.Delete(".AspNetCore.Session"); on logout and there is a new value on login! :D Can you please update your answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: I do not explicitly set it, I have the following code on startup.cs which i think sets the session cookie 
 `            services.AddSession(options => {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });`